# how to create a file using windows API?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++, file

I want to create a text file using windows API. I studied about

```
HANDLE CreateFile(
LPCTSTR lpFileName, 
DWORD dwDesiredAccess, 
DWORD dwShareMode, 
LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, 
DWORD dwCreationDispostion , 
DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, 
HANDLE hTemplateFile);
```

I can't understand how to pass the first parameter to create a file. I tried to use data-type FILE and pass it's pointer as first parameter but it's showing incompatible with LPCTSTR. Can anybody tell me how to do it? I am new in using windows API. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LPCTSTR` is the same as `const TCHAR*` ("Long Pointer to a Constant `TCHAR`-String"), which is either `const wchar_t*` or `const char*` depending on the character set. So just pass in a string surrounded by `_T()`, like:

```
CreateFile(_T("C:\\File.txt"), FILE_READ_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
```

(By the way, `FILE` is not part of the Windows SDK; it's part of the standard C runtime library, and it's internally *based* on `CreateFile`, which creates a file based on its name.)

Comment: can you name the header file for _T please. I have included <windows.h> and <stdio.h>. but it's showing _T is undefined.

Comment: Thanks buddy , it's done. I was too lazy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Fun fact: the `TEXT()` macro does the same thing, but it's just defined in a different header file... feel free to use that instead, if you want. :)

Comment: Problem has not solved. The code is running without error but There is no file created in C drive. I tried with both _T and TEXT().

Comment: @narayanpatra: Did you check the return value from `CreateFile`?  If it returned either `NULL` or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, you should call `GetLastError` to find out why.  Do you have permission to write to the directory?  Using the Win32 API doesn't bypass permission checks.

Comment: +1, nice recommendation. If you can't solve it, feel free to share the code so we can take a look.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Mistake was somewhere else. Now it's working fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Pass the *name* of the file.  A string.  Use the SDK [example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/opening-a-file-for-reading-or-writing).

Comment: In that example , file name is passed by command line. I want to hard code it in my code.

Answer (score 2):

To create file with `CreateFile()` function :

```
CreateFile("OUTPUT_FILE", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

The first parameter is the name of the file which you can pass from any string variable..for example if the filename is in CString variable you can pass (LPCTSTR) variblename to convert it to LPCTSTR. all the other parameters are depending on your implementation whether you want to create the file always or append to existing file etc...